# Create a view from slug blog title in plain php

Tags: php, mysql, url-routing

I've seen a lot of material on how to generate a unique slug title and then store it in the database.

I want to make a blog with urls like `blog/my-first-post`  and then get the content from the db and make the view. 
Let's say I will have a very basic table with columns (**id, title, body, slug**) and I already have the generated slug in the database for each post.

How can I make a simple router in PHP that gets the url `blog/my-first-post` get the slug and search for it in the database and then get the contents of that post from the db so I assign the blog contents into an array and then make the view for that url?

All this without using a PHP framework if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could route everything to an index.php page with htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Using this htaccess file, the URLs would look like `www.website.com/blog/slug-name`

The `slug-name` part of the URL can be accessed with `$_GET['url']`

Then just get the relevant data from your database that matches the slug:

```
SELECT title, body FROM blogs WHERE slug = $_GET['url']
```

Obviously don't use that SQL, it's just an example. Make sure you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Bang on!  Just what I needed to know.